# Dict of string key-value pairs

Tags: python, string, loops, dictionary

I have a list of countries and capitals that I would like to convert into a dict.  Here, both key and value are strings.

```
from countrygroups import EUROPEAN_UNION
from countryinfo import CountryInfo

countries = EUROPEAN_UNION.names
print(countries)

['Austria', 'Belgium', 'Bulgaria', 'Croatia', 'Cyprus', 'Czechia', 'Denmark', 'Estonia', 'Finland', 'France', 'Germany', 'Greece', 'Hungary', 'Ireland', 'Italy', 'Latvia', 'Lithuania', 'Luxembourg', 'Malta', 'Netherlands', 'Poland', 'Portugal', 'Romania', 'Slovakia', 'Slovenia', 'Spain', 'Sweden', 'United Kingdom']
```

The following code will print `country:capital` for each country but how does one construct a dict from these key-value pairs in Python3?

```
for country in countries:
    if country == 'Czechia':
        country = 'Czech Republic'
    cinfo = CountryInfo(country)
    print(country  + ' : ' + cinfo.capital())


Austria : Vienna
Belgium : Brussels
Bulgaria : Sofia
Croatia : Zagreb
Cyprus : Nicosia
...
```

Comment: `your_dict[country] = cinfo.capital()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should fix the erroneous data (country name) separately.  Then use a dictionary comprehension to build the dictionary:

```
countries[countries.index('Czechia')]  = 'Czech Republic' # fix input data
dictionary = { country:CountryInfo(country).capital() for country in countries }
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace you for loop with this:

```py
countries_dict = {}
for country in countries:
    if country == 'Czechia':
        country = 'Czech Republic'

    cinfo = CountryInfo(country)
    countries_dict[country] = cinfo.capital()

    print(country  + ' : ' + cinfo.capital())
```